# How to autocaption a video?

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-streaming

I want to play videos and autocation them.
I have some training videos and I want to see speech to text like what we have in youtube.(to show text under the video)
I don’t want to upload files somewhere else.
Is there any tools or player that have speech to text convertor like youtube?
I dont mean subtitles. and Indont mean download subtitles automatically for movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried beecut? Software to auto generate subtitles. https://beecut.com/auto-subtitle-video.html

Comment: Hi. I could extract subtitles for the video by beecut. but the process take much time. I must import the video 1st, extract the subtitle  and then export the video (the output video has subtitle). Is the there any fast way? when I play the video, the program has speech recognition and the subtitle is displayed automatically.

Comment: Auto Generating subtitles takes some time. This is the fastest way that I have found. There isnt really a faster way with the way technology works